# Get all permutations of k values (k = 1...n)

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, permutation, combinations

I need a query which can be used in (or as) a function and retrieves all permutations of n values. And I need all permutations of length k where k = 1..n.

EDIT#1: Extended sample input and result so input has 3 values instead of 2 - however, number of input values may vary from 1 to n.

Example:

Input: table with values in one column in multiple rows

```
    Value  (nvarchar(500))
    ------
    Ann
    John
    Mark
```

Edit#2: I can live with any of following outputs

Output#1: table with values concatenated in one column

```
    Ann
    John
    Ann,John
    John,Ann
    Ann,Mark
    Mark,Ann
    John,Mark
    Mark,John
    Ann,John,Mark
    Ann,Mark,John
    John,Ann,Mark
    John,Mark,Ann
    Mark,Ann,John
    Mark,John,Ann
```

Output#2: table with id of permutation/combination, value and order

```
    id    value    order
    --------------------
    1     Ann      1
    2     John     1
    3     Ann      1
    3     John     2
    4     John     1
    5     Ann      2
```

Notes:

- must work on SQL Server 2008 R2
- must work within function
- maximum number of expected distinct elements in input should never exceed 5 - if this matters for performance or any other reason
- Value column in input table is not likely to exceed 200 characters in length - if this matters for performance or any other reason

After a lot of searching over the Internet I've found [Generating Permutations in T-SQL](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic218243-186-2.aspx#bm634104) forum thread but I didn't manage to modify it to give expected output format as well as force it to make k = 1...n permutations also.

There are a lot of solutions to similar problems mostly written in non-SQL language, but I was unable to find the one that would help me to achieve solve this particular problem.

Comment: What have you tried?  Perhaps an n-way self join with a constraint the selected fields are not equal to one another?

Comment: @RaymondHettinger: I've tried to modify code from the link specified in question. Also tried to modify various other solutions but a lot of articles' authors misunderstood permutations and combinatons. And this is a mix of both. N-join like multiple cross joins? No, it doesn't work because I don't know number of values upfront (as stated in question k=1...n).

Comment: May be tough luck then.  I don't know of any parameterized SQL query that returns a variable length number of fields.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger: I am aware that varible-number-of-return-columns query can't be written. I need concatenated values in one column as specified in question. But I could live with solution that will return three fields: id of permutation, value and order within permutation, so i could identify values within permutation easily (just edited my post to include this output)

Comment: You need a query? What about a stored procedure?

Comment: possible duplicate of [All possible combinations for two column data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005099/all-possible-combinations-for-two-column-data) As far as I can see my answer there should do what you need.

Comment: Ah actually I didn't notice you want to return both `(a,b,c)` and `(a,c,b)` so it will need adjusting.

Comment: @OcasoProtal, having query would be the easiest solution for me to insert into legacy code. Stored procedure would require refactoring few functions and stored procedures.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
;WITH Names(Name) As
(
SELECT 'Ann' UNION ALL
SELECT 'John' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mark' 
), R(Name,Lvl) AS
(
SELECT CAST(',' + Name AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 1
FROM Names
UNION ALL
SELECT R.Name + ',' + N.Name, Lvl + 1
FROM R JOIN Names N ON R.Name + ',' NOT LIKE '%,' + N.Name + ',%'
)
SELECT STUFF(Name,1,1,'') AS Name
FROM R
ORDER BY Lvl, Name
```

Returns

```
Name
------------------------------
Ann
John
Mark
Ann,John
Ann,Mark
John,Ann
John,Mark
Mark,Ann
Mark,John
Ann,John,Mark
Ann,Mark,John
John,Ann,Mark
John,Mark,Ann
Mark,Ann,John
Mark,John,Ann
```

Comment: Martin, this is perfect solution, thanks a lot! Seems I was overcomplicating my T-SQL code.

Comment: @FilipPopović I've assumed your actual data doesn't contain any commas or characters of special significance to the `LIKE` operator. If this is not the case then it may need tweaking.

Comment: Martin, data is column names of some table. In my case, there will be columns with underscore. I did a quick test and for my particular test case it is working but I would really appreciate if You can tweak your query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @FilipPopović - Just change the join condition to `FROM R JOIN Names N ON  CHARINDEX(',' + N.Name + ',',R.Name + ',',1) = 0 `